# How to remove format description in date_popup form field?

Tags: datetime, input-formats

How can I remove format description in date_popup form field?

```
$form['payable_by'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#title' => $amount !== '' ? t('Instalment payable date for instalment @label', array('@label' => $amount)) : t('Instalment payable date for new instalment'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#default_value' => $payable_by,
    '#parents' => array('instalment', $key, 'payable_by'),
        '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
        '#date_year_range' => '-0:+1',
  );
```

Please check the image

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Normally, you would just set the *#description* property of the form element, and it would be rendered. With the *date_popup* element implemented by the Date module it seems it is not possible: The form element is made of two sub-elements for which the value of the *#description* property is not taken into consideration.

As there are two branches, I will report what I have noticed in the development snapshot for both the branches.

#### Branch 7.x-2

The "date_popup" element is defined with the [following code](http://drupalcode.org/project/date.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/date_popup/date_popup.module).

```
function date_popup_element_info() {
  $timepicker = date_popup_get_preferred_timepicker();
  $type['date_popup'] = array(
    '#input' => TRUE,
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#date_timezone' => date_default_timezone(),
    '#date_flexible' => 0,
    '#date_format' => variable_get('date_format_short', 'm/d/Y - H:i'),
    '#timepicker' => variable_get('date_popup_timepicker', $timepicker),
    '#date_increment' => 1,
    '#date_year_range' => '-3:+3',
    '#date_label_position' => 'above',
    '#process' => array('date_popup_element_process'),
    '#value_callback' => 'date_popup_element_value_callback',
    '#theme_wrappers' => array('date_popup'),
  );
  if (module_exists('ctools')) {
    $type['date_popup']['#pre_render'] = array('ctools_dependent_pre_render');
  }
  return $type;
}
```

The element has a process function that execute the following code.

```
  $element['#tree'] = TRUE;
  $element['#theme_wrappers'] = array('date_popup');

  if (!empty($element['#ajax'])) {
    $element['#ajax'] += array(
      'trigger_as' => array('name' =>$element['#name']),
      'event' => 'change',
    );
  }

  $element['date'] = date_popup_process_date_part($element);
  $element['time'] = date_popup_process_time_part($element);
```

Looking at the code for `date_popup_process_date_part()`, I notice the following code.

```
  $sub_element['#value'] = $sub_element['#default_value'];
  // TODO, figure out exactly when we want this description. In many places it is not desired.
  $sub_element['#description'] = ' '. t('E.g., @date', array('@date' => date_format_date(date_now(), 'custom', date_popup_date_format($element))));
```

As the code that `date_popup_element_process()` executes before to return the element is the following one, there is still an alternative.

```
  $context = array(
   'form' => $form,
  );
  drupal_alter('date_popup_process', $element, $form_state, $context);
```

Implementing `hook_date_popup_process_alter()` you could remove the description.

```
function mymodule_date_popup_process_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  unset($element['date']['#description']);
  unset($element['time']['#description']);
}
```

Similar code is present in the branch [6.x-2](http://drupalcode.org/project/date.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-2.x:/date_popup/date_popup.module).

#### Branch 7.x-1

There are few differences with the branch I previously described. (See [the code repository](http://drupalcode.org/project/date.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/date_popup/date_popup.module).)

The first is the code that in `date_popup_process_date_part()` sets the description, which is the following one.

```
  $sub_element['#value'] = $sub_element['#default_value'];
  // TODO, figure out exactly when we want this description. In many places it is not desired.
  $sub_element['#description'] = ' '. t('Format: @date', array('@date' => date_format_date(date_now(), 'custom', date_popup_date_format($element))));
  return $sub_element;
```

The second difference is that `date_popup_element_process()` (the process function for that element) is not invoking `hook_date_popup_process_alter()`.

```
function date_popup_element_process($element, $form_state, $form) {
  date_popup_add();
  module_load_include('inc', 'date_api', 'date_api_elements');

  $element['#tree'] = TRUE;
  $element['#theme_wrappers'] = array('date_popup');

  $element['date'] = date_popup_process_date($element);
  $element['time'] = date_popup_process_time($element);

  if (isset($element['#element_validate'])) {
    array_push($element['#element_validate'], 'date_popup_validate');
  }
  else {
    $element['#element_validate'] = array('date_popup_validate');
  }
  return $element;
}
```

The only alternative in this case would be to implement [hook_element_info_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/7) to add a process function to the element.

```
function mymodule_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  if (isset($type['date_popup'])) {
    $type['date_popup']['#process'][] = 'mymodule_date_popup_process';
  }
}

function mymodule_date_popup_process($element, $form_state, $complete_form) {
  unset($element['date']['#description']);
  unset($element['time']['#description']);

  return $element;
}
```

The code for branch [6.x-1](http://drupalcode.org/project/date.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/date_popup/date_popup.module) is similar to the code of branch 6.x-2.

In both the cases, the comment reported in the Date module code suggests they will alter the code not to use the description that is now shown. For this reason, I would suggest to implement the necessary code in a custom module, and remove that code once the Date module is changed.

Comment: The implementation of hook_element_info_alter() to add a process function to the element worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function promo_quote_date_popup_process($element, $form_state, $complete_form) {
      unset($element['date']['#description']);
      unset($element['date']['#title']);
      return $element;
}
function promo_quote_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  if (isset($type['date_popup'])) {
    $type['date_popup']['#process'][] = 'promo_quote_date_popup_process';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In d 6.x there is no info_alter hook. But you can solve this by using pre_render.

In you form definition or by form alter you need to add a pre_render definition. Like this for example (in form definition):

```
$form['dateformname'] = array(
  '#title' => t('The date'),
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  '#pre_render' => array('MODULENAME_date_prerender'),
);
```

And then implement that prerender function where you can unset the data sub element description. Example:

```
function MODULENAME_date_prerender($element) {
  unset($element['date']['#description']);
  return $element;
}
```