# Drupal form API date popup

Tags: 6, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove format description in date_popup form field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28228/how-to-remove-format-description-in-date-popup-form-field)

Hi I am creating a drupal 6 module and I have used drupal form API date popup fields to allow users to enter date. Everything is going on fine but I am getting a format description for date popup field as FORMAT 23/05/2012. I don't know how to remove this description.As shown in the image below[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make a correct format you can make use of `#default_value`

See [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#date)

> **Description**: Format a date selection box. The #default_value will be
>   today's date if no value is supplied. The format for the #default_value and the #return_value is an array with three elements with the keys: 'year', month', and 'day'. For example, array('year' =>
>   2007, 'month' => 2, 'day' => 15)

Comment: As you can see in the above image I want to remove the text "Format 23/05/2012" from the display

Comment: I think you can make it work using the Display field settings in nodes Manage Display page admin/content/node-type/<machinenameofyournode>/display

Comment: But I have used drupal form API and created a date popup form field for this

Comment: In that case try unset or override `#description` field

Answer (score 0):

try CSS to remove it. insert some body and page classes.