# How to fully localize popup calendar field

Tags: datetime

Strangely my popup calendar is localized, showing day names and so on in correct language, but not the date in the textfield neither in the description, **which remained Y-m-d formatted**.

[image].

**This should be french format : d-m-Y** . And I also need to change default value from today to next week. So, as per [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28228/how-to-remove-format-description-in-date-popup-form-field#answer-28235) :

> (For date popup) Branch 7.x-2 : 
>   Implementing `hook_date_popup_process_alter()` you could remove the description...

I tried these diff snippets :

```
function vts_commerce_date_popup_process_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  $element['#date_format'] = 'd-m-Y';//no effect
  $element['date']['#date_format'] = 'd-m-Y';//no effect
  $element['#default_value'] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+1 week'));//no effect
  unset($element['date']['#description']);//works but I need to display it with correct date format instead 
  dsm($element);
  return $element;
}
```

From which snippets 4 changes the form element. Instead, snippets 1, 2, 3 changed $element into `dsm()` returned values, but change nothing in the form. So my questions are:

- **How to display date into the textfield and in its description in french format ?** how to change the default value that will be shown on page loading ?
- What is the difference here between `$element['#foo']` and `$element['date']['#foo']` ?

Many thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm a bit ashamed :( No need to do such complicated things. In the edit field page, there are some advanced settings and values I had never paid attention to :

- **Date entry options** : control the order and format of the options users see.

[image: Date entry options]

- **Default date** : Relative default value (*Describe a time by reference to the current day, like '+90 days' (90 days from the day the field is created) or '+1 Saturday' (the next Saturday). See strtotime for more details*.

[image: Default date : Relative default value]

Comment: Anyway, I would be happy to know an=bout the 2nd question... What is the difference in hook_date_popup_process_alter() between $element['#foo'] and $element['date']['#foo'] ?