# Where to input hook_element_info_alter() to remove format description in date_popup form field?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I want to remove format description in date_popup form field (code posted [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28228/how-to-remove-format-description-in-date-popup-form-field#)). The solution requires me to implement hook_element_info_alter() to add a process function to the element.

I found the code I was looking for, but being a novice, I don't know where to input it?

Could someone please guide me?

I have Drupal 7.53 with Date Module Version: 7.x-2.9 installed

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom module.

You can follow [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/howtos/how-to-make-a-simple-module-with-a-form-and-menu-link) to creating your first module.

However you won't need any form code... just your element info alter, and process function. After enabling and clearing cache, you should see the desired behavior you are after.