# How do I alter the HTML outputted by an exposed filter?

Tags: 7, hooks, views

I have a view that pulls in content of many different types. I gave the user two exposed filters, using the [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module. However, the two filters look different. I would like them to look the same.

[image]

Specifically, I would like to get rid of the "Start date", "End date", and "E.g., 2017-02-01" labels on the filter on the right hand side.

How do I do this? Is it possible to do it within the view settings? If not, I don't mind writing a custom solution. I imagine there's a relevant hook somewhere, but I do not know which one to use.

Comment: have you tried editing the 'label' in the view field?

Comment: The setting I'm looking for isn't there :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out these settings can't be changed in the View (that I was able to find, and I looked pretty extensively). But, with Drupal's module/hook system, it's a pretty quick fix.

Source: [How to remove format description in date_popup form field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28228/how-to-remove-format-description-in-date-popup-form-field)

First, get rid of **Start date** and replace **End date** with **And** to match the filter on the left:

```
function edit_date_form_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] === "views-exposed-form-editable-content-page") {
    $form["field_editor_review_date_value_1"]["min"]["#title"] = "";
    $form["field_editor_review_date_value_1"]["max"]["#title"] = "And";
  }
}
```

Then, get rid of the **E.g., 2017-02-01**:

```
function edit_date_form_date_popup_process_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  $element['date']['#description'] = "";
  $element['time']['#description'] = "";
}
```

Plop those into a module, enable it, and your output is:

[image]